Do we have any option to edit multilist in sitecore pages in XM cloud?
I have added multilist from the content tree. Now, content authors need to switch between content tree and Sitecore pages to edit the selected items every time.
Do we have any customization available here?
Thanks in advance.

It is not recommended to do any customization in Sitecore XM Cloud.

Sitecore XM Cloud is a SaaS product where Sitecore is always rolling out new changes incrementally. So it is no wise to make customization as it may conflict with the new updates leading to the Sitecore instance being broken.
If there is really a change or update needed, it should be on the head application (frontend website).
The CM instance should be used as is mostly


Currently, Sitecore XM Cloud pages do not support editing features for fields like Droplist, DropLink, Multilist, TreeList, or any of their variants with search functionality directly within the Pages interface. While you can include these fields on the Pages editor, editing them requires navigating to the Content Explorer.

And even in the content explorer, these fields are displayed as pipe separated Guid's

Sitecore XM cloud does not support editing features for fields like Droplist, DropLink, Multilist, TreeList also if your trying to implement it with some workaround ( that even is possible) but it is not recommended to do any customization in Sitecore XM Cloud

How about trying rendering parameters instead?
They show up to the right in Pages, allowing authors to easily make changes without navigating back and forth to the content tree.
If you keep it simple—like using checkboxes, text input fields, or dropdown lists—it can make the authoring experience smoother.
